# How to export file names from last commit?

Tags: python, git

I managed to find out the last commit id using python:

```
import subprocess


def get_git_revision_hash():
    full_hash = subprocess.check_output(['git', 'rev-parse', 'HEAD'])
    full_hash = str(full_hash, "utf-8").strip()
    return full_hash

def get_git_revision_short_hash():
    short_hash = subprocess.check_output(['git', 'rev-parse', '--short', 'HEAD'])
    short_hash = str(short_hash, "utf-8").strip()
    return short_hash

last_commit= get_git_revision_hash()
```

But now I don't know how to transform this git command in python: `git ls-tree --name-only -r last_commit ->files.txt`, so I can get file names in text file.

Comment: If you're doing this with any frequency, let me point out there is a Python GIT API available:  https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Comment: Note that there is no need to turn `HEAD` into a revision hash ID first here: you can run `git ls-tree --name-only -r HEAD`. If you have already done the work of turning `HEAD` into a revision hash ID for some *other* good reason, though, it is *slightly* (very slightly) more efficient to give the raw hash ID to Git like this.

Answer (score 0):

You are too close, you just need to get the files first then write them to a file:

```
>>> files = subprocess.check_output(['git', 'ls-tree', '--name-only', '-r', last_commit]).decode('utf8')
>>> with open('files.txt', 'w') as f:
...    print(files, file=f)
```

After this, a file named `'files.txt.'` should appear in the working directory with desired content.